# How to create multiple wizards under 'actions' menu for one model in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

how can i create multiple action wizards under "actions" menu for one model.
For example i need to create "Wizard 1 , wizard 2 and wizard 3" under "Actions" menu for a model (MyModel).

Answer (score 2):

You can create using different external ids.

```xml
<act_window name="string"  context="{}" res_model="res_model"
src_model="src_model" id="act_unique_id"/>

<act_window name="string"  context="{}" res_model="res_model"
src_model="src_model" id="act_unique_id1"/>
```

> You need to set context in the action, so when action will call you
>   will get context in python file.
>
> Based on context value you can easily execute your code.

This may help you.